# Find an upper bound for $|f(x)-P_4(x)|$, for $0 \le x \le 0.4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

So I'm stuck on something that is supposed to be fairly easy...

[image: Problem]

I was able to work through the Taylor polynomial which I believe to be:

$$x+x^3+\frac{x^5}{2!}+\frac{x^7}{3!}+\frac{x^9}{4!}$$

**But I'm stuck on the upper bound.**
I don't know how to go about finding it. Like something I learned so long ago and can't figure out for the life of me. My teacher told me to put the equation on a graph but when I do I don't know what the bounds would be as I think it would just approach infinity? But I don't know since the problem states a given range.

Graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zy7fjl26zz
[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only supposed to consider the interval $0\leq x\leq 0.4$.

The difference $|f(x)-p_4(x)|$ is bounded by the error term in the Taylor polynomial. In this case, you have 
$$
|f(x)-p_4(x)|\leq \frac{e^c\,|x|^{11}}{5!},
$$
where $0\leq c\leq 0.4$. So 
$$
|f(x)-p_4(x)|\leq \frac{e^{0.4}\,0.4^{11}}{5!}\leq \frac{2\times 0.4^{11}}{120}=0.000000699050\overline6\leq10^{-6}.
$$

Comment: Just to clerify, are you saying the upper bound is $10^-6$ and the 0.0000006990506 = $|f(x)−p4(x)|$?

Comment: No. If you were able to calculate $f(x)-p_4(x)$ exactly, you would be able to calculate $f(x)$ exactly; besides, it depends on $x$, it is not constant. To get to the number $\frac{2\times 0.4^{11}}{120}$, I first bounded the derivative $e^c$ in the remainder the Taylor polynomial with $e^{0.4}$, and then bounded $e^{0,4}$ with $2$.

Comment: Oh okay so I guess I'm just wondering how you got $< 10^-6$. Is it just simply because $0.0000006990506 = 6.99... x 10^-7$? I guess I'm trying to ask what makes you determine that as the bound

Comment: Yes, it's just that. It's annoying and unnecessary to write the long number, so it is enough to notice that it is just a tad bigger than $\tfrac12\,10^{-6}$. Of course, if you  had an application where the precision of the estimate is essential, one can be more careful.